# What's the second area to explore in Brigantine Isles?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am trying to get the *Krytan Explorer* achievement in Guild Wars 2 but I am stuck in the Brigantine Isles. Looking at the list of areas to explore for the achievement, I see that there are two entries for Brigantine Isles:

[image]

I don't understand where the second one in the list would be. Looking at my map, I don't see any areas I might have obviously missed:

[image]

I have also tried swimming around the area to make sure I didn't forget any underwater area. So, where is this second *Gendarran Fields: Brigantine Isles* area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find an official word on this, but did find [several reddit threads](https://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/3quds5/krytan_explorer_achievement_bug_or_unlucky/) where players have run into the same issue.  The general consensus seems to be that this is a display bug in the achievement window, and the achievement should still be awarded so long as you've gotten everything else and completely unfogged the map.